# Visual Studio doesn't recognize Resources object for GlobalResources

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, translation, multilingual

I'm trying to access my GlobalResource object using the following syntax:

Resources.Translation.key

However in code behind Visual Studio 2012 doesn't recognize the `Resources` object.

I created a resx file named `Translation.en-resx` in the App_GlobalResources folder that I've added using left click Add on the project name to add this folder.

I've create da single word inside that file "Name" and "Nom".

I want to know why Visual Studio doesn't recognize the `Resources` object?

**Update**: I also noticed that Visual Studio doesn't recognized the object `GetLocalResourceObject` as well.

I am using a ASP.NET Web Project in Visual Studio using C# as the language.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename the file `Translation.en-resx` to `Translation.en.resx`. The difference is the dot between the `en` and the `resx` ... and don't forget to edit the "Custom Tool Namespace" property of the resource file.

This link ([ASP.NET MVC 3 Internationalization](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx)) provides a good tutorial about how to use Resources.